# PHP SQL Server Function not Returning Expected Results for Column Value Result

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am working on a function that checks if the user has saved their login credentials, but when checking and the SQL Server query returns count = 0, the variables results in "undefined array". I am not sure how to fix the issue, as I am new to PHP.

Bit of context to the process:

When a user logins to the website, I am setting the $_SESSION variable "logged_in" to 'true'. The user can decide to also "remember me" to save time in logging in if they close their browser. If the user checks the "remember me" box when logging in, I am saving a unique token "remToken" and the user's UserID (created on registration) "userID" as two cookies. These two values get inserted into the database.

The objective is that on each page of the website, I run a function that checks if the $_SESSION['logged_in'] is set and set to 'true'. If yes, $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;, else $_SESSION['logged_in'] = false;

Next, check if the user has active remToken and userID cookies. If yes, check for a matching active remToken and UserID set in the database. If yes, set $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;, else unset the remToken and userID cookies and set $_SESSION['logged_in'] = false;

Finally, return $_SESSION['logged_in'];

When running the SQL query in the database, it returns 0 (expected for this example, as I am testing the function). When echoing out "echo $returnCount;", it results in the error "UNDEFINED VARIABLE $RETURNCOUNT". When the count from the query is 1, it properly returns 1. $pdo variable is correctly set and works in other queries.

```
function cookie_RememberMeCheck($pdo) {
    //Function expectation:
    //If the session "logged_in" is not set and not true, set it to false
    //Next, check if the user has active "remember me" cookies. If they do, set the logged_in state to "true"
        //If the user has inactive "remember me" cookies, set "logged_in" to false

    //If the user has not logged in during this session, set the logged_in value to "false". If they have logged in, set the session to "true"
    if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true) {
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = false;
    }
    

    //Check if the cookies "remToken" and "userID" have been set
    if (isset($_COOKIE['remToken']) && isset($_COOKIE['userID'])) {

        //Set the values of the UserID and remToken so we can match them to the database
        $cookie_userID = $_COOKIE['userID'];
        $cookie_remToken = $_COOKIE['remToken'];


        $sqlStmt = 'select count(*) as RemCount from DessertBar..UserRemLogin rl with (nolock) where rl.UserID = :userID and rl.RemToken = :remToken and rl.isActive = 1';
        $sqlStmtPrepare = $pdo->prepare($sqlStmt);
        $sqlStmtPrepare->bindParam(':userID', $cookie_userID);
        $sqlStmtPrepare->bindParam(':remToken', $cookie_remToken);
        $sqlStmtPrepare->execute();
        $returnCount = $sqlStmtPrepare->fetchColumn();

        if ($returnCount > 0) {
            //If user has active cookies in database, set logged_in state to true
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
        } else {
            //If the user does not have active cookies in the database, destroy the cookies and logout the user
            unset($_COOKIE['userID']);
            unset($_COOKIE['remToken']);

            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = false;
        }

    }

    //Finally, return the result of the logged_in state for the user
    //return $_SESSION['logged_in'];
    echo $returnCount;
}
```

The desired result is that if `COUNT(*)` in `sqlStmt` is 0, then the `$returnCount` variable would also be 0. The SQL script is working fine as far as I can tell, but PHP is not correctly pulling the value of the `COUNT(*)` statement is what I think.

Comment: display what is contained in $returnCount - var_dump($returnCount)

Comment: In your real code do you check the results of `prepare()`, `bindParam()`, `execute()` and `fetchColumn()` to see if they return `false`?